# Java type class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and MIME media type multipart/form-data was not found

Tags: jersey, tomcat7, multipartform-data, multipart

I see following error in my tomcat logs...

> ERROR c.s.j.spi.container.ContainerRequest - A message body reader for
>   Java class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and Java type
>   class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and MIME media type
>   multipart/form-data was not found. The registered message body readers
>   compatible with the MIME media type are:
>   */* ->   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
>   com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General

---

On the client side i see following msg:

> POST https://dev.project.org/upload returned a response status of 415
>   Unsupported Media Type.

---

I have googled around and the advise is that jersey-multipart.jar and mimepull.jar are needed as dependencies. I have following dependency in my build.gradle:

> compile 'com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:1.18'

After packaging and deploying the app on the tomcat(Apache Tomcat/7.0.47) i see that **jersey-multipart-1.18.jar** and **mimepull-1.9.3.jar** are in the **app/WEB-INF/lib** folder.

---

Following is my server-side code:

```
@POST
  @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
  @Path("/v2/upload")
  public Response uploadV2(FormDataMultiPart multipart) {

      logger.info("**POST /v2/upload");

      return Response.ok("success!").build();

  }
```

I am still getting the same errors on the server and client sides. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you simply need to add mimepull.jar to your lib

or with Maven

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.mimepull</groupId>
    <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

I also was getting this same behavior, receiving a response of 415 Unsupported Media Type. If my input parameter was a String, I could hit path. As soon as I change the param to FormDataMultiPart, I would get the 415. What solved it for me was making sure my com.sun.jersey packages were of the same version.

With maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any mismatch of jersey-multipart would give me the mentioned behavior.